# Key derivation functions (KDF) with EOS private key

Tags: security

For our application we would like to derive hundreds of keys from an EOS private key without compromising the key. Is there any way to do this in EOS currently or any recommended external library to use?

Comment: I think this is mathematically possible but not secure to do.

Comment: you mean bip32/bip39/bip44, it's possible to generate a master key for many eos private keys

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by deriving keys?  Are you using the key to seed the randomness generator for other keys?

If that's the case and you're also trying to create EOS owner account keys with this method, then I see a security risk.

You could alternatively create a custom permission level that only applies to your application and create keys for that.  This would allow the EOS user to utilize their owner and active authorities to remove this permission level or alter it if need be.